# CakePHP: view containing underscore in filename not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Trying to use the [Cakephp Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#view-conventions) in naming my view file.

Here is my Controller (/app/Controller/CallbacksController.php):

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class CallbacksController extends AppController {

    public function googlePlus() {

    }
}

?>
```

I have named my view /app/View/Callbacks/google_plus.ctp.

When I try to go to that view with http://mycakephpapp.dev/callbacks/google_plus.ctp, it gives the following error:

> Missing Method in CallbacksController
>
> Error: The action google_plus is not defined in controller
>   CallbacksController
>
> Error: Create CallbacksController::google_plus() in file:
>   app\Controller\CallbacksController.php.

If I rename the view to googleplus.ctp, it works just fine.

**Can anyone shed some light on why this particular Naming Convention is not working?**

Comment: The url you are opening is refering to a method named `google_plus`

If you change the url to `http://mycakephpapp.dev/callbacks/googlePlus` everything should work as expected. 

If you want to use it your way, i think you should create some routes with the `Router` class.

Comment: By convention it should be `public function google_plus() {}`. Then your view file would also be correctly named (google_plus.ctp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Cake standards both the view and the function should be named google_plus.

Comment: Directly quoted from CakePHP's Naming Conventions: "View template files are named after the controller functions they display, in an underscored form. The getReady() function of the PeopleController class will look for a view template in /app/View/People/get_ready.ctp.

The basic pattern is /app/View/Controller/underscored_function_name.ctp." Am I just reading this wrong??

Comment: That is confusing the way they say it. But keeping the action name and view name the same definitely works.